# Are there any solutions to make highlighted when displayed the output (result) value from input? The result like numbers should displayed in highlight

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a conversion webpage, which focuses on three main conversion calculators that are "length" "weight/mass" and "temperature" conversion program. I got troubles with the "length" conversion program, its output result is a number, and I don't know how to make it highlighted in yellow.

I tried to use `document.getElementById('result').style.backgroundColor = "yellow";` (at the last line of my code). But just made its background become yellow, that's not what I want to do.

The main thing is I would like to make the result input (which you can see the `placeholder="Result"`) to display the result, and then that result (which is a number that has been converted from meters unit to any units, for example, foot unit) will be highlighted in yellow, just like highlighted a text from a document.

I just tried to put the background color to consider what to make that result to be highlighted in yellow, but not the `input` background in yellow.

[How to create a JavaScript program that makes the output result (right side input) display as highlighted in yellow like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7pAN.png)

```js
/*============== LENGTH CONVERSION ==============*/
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var inputType = document.getElementById('inputType');
var resultType = document.getElementById('resultType');
var option_from, option_to;
var result1 = document.getElementById('result').value;

// now add listener
input.addEventListener("keyup", myResult);
inputType.addEventListener("change", myResult);
resultType.addEventListener("change", myResult);

// taking initial value
option_from = inputType.value;
option_to = resultType.value;


function myResult() {
  // when we change the input and output type vale we need to updata the 
  // option_from and option_to
  option_from = inputType.value;
  option_to = resultType.value;

  // now compare the input and resultType value and add formula
  if (option_from === "meters" && option_to === "feet") {
    //this is meters to feet formula 
    result.value = Number(input.value * 3.2808399).toFixed(2);
  } else if (option_from === "meters" && option_to === "centi") {
    //this is meters to centimeters formula 
    result.value = Number(input.value) * 100;
  } else if (option_from === "meters" && option_to === "milli") {
    //this is meters to millimeters formula 
    result.value = Number(input.value) * 1000;
  } else if (option_from === "meters" && option_to === "meters") {
    //this is meters to meters  
    result.value = input.value;
  }


  if (option_from === "feet" && option_to === "meters") {
    //this is feet to meters formula 
    result.value = Number(input.value * 0.3048).toFixed(1);

  } else if (option_from === "feet" && option_to === "centi") {
    //this is feet to centimeters formula 
    result.value = Number(input.value * 30.48).toFixed(1);

  } else if (option_from === "feet" && option_to === "milli") {
    //this is feet to centimeters formula 
    result.value = Number(input.value) * 304.8;
  } else if (option_from === "feet" && option_to === "feet") {
    //this is feet to feet  
    result.value = input.value;
  }


  if (option_from === "centi" && option_to === "meters") {
    //this is centimeters to meters formula 
    result.value = Number(input.value) * 0.01;
  } else if (option_from === "centi" && option_to === "feet") {
    //this is centimeters to feet
    result.value = Number(input.value * 0.0328084).toFixed(3);
  } else if (option_from === "centi" && option_to === "centi") {
    //this is centimeters to centimeters
    result.value = input.value;
  } else if (option_from === "centi" && option_to === "milli") {
    //this is centimeters to millimeters
    result.value = Number(input.value) * 10;
  }


  if (option_from === "milli" && option_to === "meters") {
    //this is millimeters to meters formula 
    result.value = Number(input.value) * 0.001;
  } else if (option_from === "milli" && option_to === "feet") {
    //this is millimeters to feet
    result.value = Number(input.value * 0.00328084).toFixed(4);
  } else if (option_from === "milli" && option_to === "centi") {
    //this is millimeters to centimeters
    result.value = Number(input.value) * 0.1;
  } else if (option_from === "milli" && option_to === "milli") {
    //this is millimeters to millimeters
    result.value = input.value;
  }
  document.getElementById('result').style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

```html
<!--========== CONTENTS ==========-->
<main>
  <!-- length section start -->
  <section class="convert-length" id="lenght-convert">
    <div class="lenght-content">
      <h2 class="title">Conversion Calculator</h2>
      <div class="length-converter-body">
        <div class="text converter-title">Length Converter</div>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Input" id="input">
        <span>=</span>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Result" id="result">

        <select id="inputType">
          <option value="meters">Meters</option>
          <option value="feet">Foot</option>
          <option value="centi">Centimeters</option>
          <option value="milli">Millimeters</option>
        </select>

        <select id="resultType">
          <option value="meters">Meters</option>
          <option value="feet">Foot</option>
          <option value="centi">Centimeters</option>
          <option value="milli">Millimeters</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users review [ask] and take the [tour] to best understand how to use the site and benefit from posting questions. I would suggest that you lack a clear, understandable question here.  You have a title that briefly describes the issue, but your post body adds not context; it is merely a collection of images. Also, please note that it is [not acceptable to post images of code on the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6831341)-- the code should be posted as text in the question body. Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Why do you overwrite `result.value` at the end in `result.value = document.getElementById('result').style.backgroundColor = "yellow";`?

Comment: @SebastianSimon because I tried to make the output value (result) from the `input` displayed in highlighted `result.value` but the `document.getElementById('result').style.backgroundColor = "yellow";` just made its background become yellow and can't display the result of the conversion.

Comment: already when i type the text,the result box get's highlighted ,what more?

Comment: @Neptotech-vishnu I tried to select or get the result value, but I don't know how to make that result value is highlighted when displayed on the result `placeholder="Result"`. Like when the result input displayed the result, the result will be highlighted in yellow.

Comment: @TomLe So have you considered simply removing the `result.value =` from that line?

Comment: @SebastianSimon yes sir, I did, I removed the `result.value` the problem here is I would like to make the result input display the result, and then that result will be highlighted in yellow, just like highlighted a text from a document. I just tried to put the background color to consider what to make that result to be highlighted in yellow, but not the input background in yellow.

Comment: @TomLe Yes, that works already if you remove that part of the line. [Edit] your post and provide a [mre] of what you currently have.

Comment: yes, I edited my post, I hope it would make sense.

Comment: Works perfectly fine in the snippet. Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs). [Rubber Duck Debug](//rubberduckdebugging.com/) your code. Please try using the [debugging capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a) of your browser. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** tab. Inspect your elements. What do the applied CSS rules reveal?

Comment: I just edited it, the snippet works fine now, but the resulting output still has a yellow background, any solutions, please?

Answer (score -1):

You can use  HTML element which will highlight its content in yellow without any css. Check it out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark).

Comment: Thank you for your support! Unfortunately, this is not the correct solution.